# simple SECURITY AUTHENTICATION without username/password yields results

Tags: java, ldap, apacheds

Why does this work?

```
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://localhost:10389/o=csRepository");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
//env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=John Eipe, ou=employees, o=csRepository");
//env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "qwer1234");

DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
//operations on ctx
```

My understanding is that when SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION is specified as simple and no username or password is specified then it should throw javax.naming.AuthenticationException.

Comment: Maybe because credentials were cached? You initially had the code then commented it out right?

Comment: To test my hypothesis - uncomment your authentication lines then change the password so it fails. Comment out again - does it still fail?

Comment: No its the same. btw cached where? I'm running this from psvm code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. Sadly that's how it works. 
It's stated as below in Oracle docs.

> If you supply an empty string, an empty byte/char array, or null to
>   the Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS environment property, then the
>   authentication mechanism will be "none". This is because the LDAP
>   requires the password to be nonempty for simple authentication. The
>   protocol automatically converts the authentication to "none" if a
>   password is not supplied.

This causes serious security breach. But, I guess it is left to the application to validate.

Comment: That is indeed a big hole! Thanks for sharing the solution!